# facebook connect for third party widgets?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am building a third-party widget without using an iframe. When widget is rendered, it actually creates a DOM structure inside third party page DOM. I have facebook button in my widget and I would like my users to use "facebook connect" to connect with my app. This works if I render the widget inside of an iframe. But Facebook connect doesnt work if its loaded on third party page. Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to load their iframe via php?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "load their iframe via php". Can you explain more?

Comment: @Manish - i did not think well. I thought the problem might be, hat the facebook stuff would be loaded from another Location than facebook expected (not yoursite.com but widgetsite.com) you could have solved that by proxying it via php like yoursite.com/loadfb.php and getting this data via cross-domain json. [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) 

It seems you're having a different issue. How do you load the facebook connect widget? Javascript? Iframe?
You could put your code on jsfiddle, so we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So what I take from your question is that you are developing a third party plugin of sorts that others would be able to utilize on their site. If this is the case, in order to make facebook connect work, you are going to have to load the iframe from your server, and to do cross domain stuff to and from your widget just use jsonp and provide an api. Thus, all requests to and from your widget via facebook connect with be with your appId and your domain, and all 3rd party interaction with your widget will be through your server + jsonp. In theory this work around would work, but I am not sure if i am answering your question. I think this is maybe what is meant by leosok above.

http://json-p.org/ -- a quick tutorial on jsonp

http://php.net/ -- the php website (for learning server side programming)

http://w3schools.com/ -- a great learning resource for all things web dev related

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html --windows apache server package with all the nuts and bolts you need to build your own dev env

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html -- same as last link but for linux flavors

Comment: thanks for the response. I trying to avoid rendering the entire widget inside of an iframe. However, it seems like there is no way to get "facebook connect" working on third-party page if I dont use an iframe. What do you think about rendering just the "facebook" button inside of an iframe? is that a bad idea?

Comment: I dont think so, I mean, I dont think theres much harm in it, plus as an added bonus you will get access to each plugin user's usage stats. Also, if you are going to go down that road, i would consider making the button in an iframe a javascript factory for customization purposes.